# Set ```is_active``` to False by default

Tags: django

In my custom user I need to set the `is_active` to false.

So I try this in my custom model manager:

```
    def _create_user(self, email, password, **extra_fields):
        """
        Create and save a user with the given email and password
        """
        if not email:
            raise ValueError('The given email must be set')

        email = self.normalize_email(email)
        user = self.model(email=email, **extra_fields)
        user.password = make_password(password)
        user.is_active = False <<---- HERE
        user.save(using=self._db)
        return user
```

This doesn't work and when I create a new user in the Admin site, `is_active` is still True.

So I try this approach:

```
    def create_user(self, email, password=None, **extra_fields):
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_active', False) <<---- HERE
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_staff', False)
        extra_fields.setdefault('is_superuser', False)
        return self._create_user(email, password, **extra_fields)
```

Again, this doesn't work either and `is_active` is True when I create a new user in the Admin site.

Finally I do this:

```
class CustomUser(AbstractUser):
    ......
    is_active = models.BooleanField(
        _('active'),
        default=False,
        help_text=_(
            'Designates whether this user should be treated as active. Unselect this instead of deleting user.'
        ),
    )
    ...
```

This one works, however I'd like to know why the first two approaches didn't.

Comment: Did you connect your *"custom model manager"* to `CustomUser` model?

Comment: The whole thing wouldn't work if I didn't.

Answer (score -2):

You can use signals to achieve this.Create a signals.py in the app and do something like this

```
@receiver(post_save, sender=CustomUser)
def notice(sender, instance,created, **kwargs):
    if created:
        instance.is_active = false
        instance.save()
```

Find details on how to use signals https://simpleisbetterthancomplex.com/tutorial/2016/07/28/how-to-create-django-signals.html

Comment: I've already achieved my goal. I'm asking **why** first two methods didn't work.